# Errors while getting many images from S3 Laravel Storage

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-storage

One of my API's routes associated with Laravel controller that returns URL of image stored on AWS S3.

I have function that looks like

```
public function getImage($params) {
  //... $image is fetched from database
  return Storage::disk('s3')->response("some_path/".$image->filename);
}
```

This codes works fine when I'm requesting few images, but when I try to use it inside some list which can be scrolled very fast some of request are failing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the failure error code?

Comment: I see 429 error code - too many requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are quickly scrolling and populating your lists, a lot of requests are being made to your server.

Laravel has a throttle middleware installed by default on your routes to mitigate security risks.

In your case you are hiring the limits of the throttle, resulting in 429 error codes.

Your PHP code is correct, your front-end code should be less greedy in trying to fetch images.

.... Or you should raise the allowed throttle amount in laravel, or remove it all together, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Can I raise limit for single route?

Comment: Yes, but it depends a bit on the Laravel version you use on how to do it. Rate limiting changed in L8, see https://www.amitmerchant.com/new-ratelimiter-facade-in-laravel-8/ You can find the default throttle middleware assigned to all routes in your `Kernel.php` file. Also check your routes for any throttle middleware. And do make sure you have rate limiters in general to mitigate security risks, like request flooding.